# How to run multiple web-sites on localhost with Apache

Tags: apache

I've recently installed LAMP on Ubuntu 22.04.
Apache version: Apache/2.4.52

What I am trying to do is to enable multiple web-sites on my localhost. I’ve read and followed a few posts on this topic however I can’t make it work.

So this is what I’ve done so far to create two sites "prj1" and "prj2":

1. Created two folders

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/prj1
sudo mkdir /var/www/prj2
```

2. Created two index files in the folders:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/prj1/index.html
sudo gedit /var/www/prj2/index.html
```

They are simple, the first states:

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

The second:

```
Web prj 2. Location:


/var/www/prj2
```

3. Set permissions:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chown -R 775 /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prj1
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prj2
```

4. Created .conf files for each project:
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/prj1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@prj1
     ServerName prj1
     
     DocumentRoot /var/www/prj1/
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
     </Directory>     
     <Directory /var/www/prj1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj1.webdock.io_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj1.webdock.io_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/prj2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@prj2
     ServerName prj2
     
     DocumentRoot /var/www/prj2/
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
     </Directory>     
     <Directory /var/www/prj2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj2.webdock.io_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj2.webdock.io_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

5. Enabled sites:

```
a2ensite prj1
a2ensite prj2
```

6. Edited apache2.conf:
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

I’ve added the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/prj1"
<Directory "/var/www/prj1">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/prj2"
<Directory "/var/www/prj2">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>
```

7. Added two lines in /etc/hosts:
   sudo gedit /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost prj1
127.0.0.1 localhost prj2
```

8. Restarted Apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

9. 

Now I am using the following URL in the browser:

```
http://prj1.localhost/
```

this works as expected, it shows:

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

However if I use http://prj2.localhost/ it still shows the first site

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're configuring

```
ServerName prj1
```

and

```
ServerName prj2
```

and you're accessing them as `http://prj1.localhost` (which does not find a matching virtual host, thus it takes the first one) and `http://prj2.localhost`, which also does not find a matching one, and also defaults to the first one. Either configure the name that you use to access the hosts, or configure an alias, e.g.

```
ServerName prj1
ServerAlias prj1.localhost
```

and

```
ServerName prj2
ServerAlias prj2.localhost
```

Comment: Hi Olaf,
I've added the lines into prj1.conf  (ServerAlias prj1.localhost) and prj2.conf  (ServerAlias prj2.localhost). Still no luck. I've tried various URL combinations:

`
http://localhost
http://prj2
http://prj2.localhost
http://prj2/localhost
http://localhost.prj2
http://localhost/prj2
`
none is working

Answer (score 0):

I've found what the problem was. In the prj2.conf the port for prj2 was 81 not 80. Honestly I don't know how that happened, I can't even say it was a typo since the whole text was copy/pasted.
Anyways, after I changed it to 80 both sites are now working.

In the file /etc/host the lines should be

> 127.0.0.1 prj1

> 127.0.0.1 prj2

The URLs are to be [http://prj1](https://prj1) and [http://prj2](https://prj2). The only thing is that the browser tells that connection to the sites "Not secure" (I don't know why).

I thank all the contributors to the post.

Regards,
Alex